Is there a synchronized implementation of the Golang container library?
Is there a synchronized implementation of the Golang container library?
Out of the box, container/list does not appear to be synchronized.  (BTW, this is an odd design choice:  rudimentary data structures are not synchronized; meanwhile, Golang proper is designed to facilitate concurrency...)

How you synchronize a container depends on the specific use case. There are many use cases you can use containers in concurrent programs with very little or no synchronization.

In those cases, we would use a non-synchronized version of container/list.  But for scenarios where you are guaranteed a possible conflict, it seems imposing the burden of synchronization on programmers is asking for a lot of repeat-patterns ... I am pretty sure that's why Java designers evolved synchronized implementations:  a simple realization that in a server-side context, conflict is the norm, not the exception.

How conflict happens is use-case specific. If you use goroutines and channels to communicate as opposed to a shared container, you don't run into such conflicts. In other words, if you write your Go programs like Java, you will end up with Java problems (shared memory). If you instead change your approach and write idiomatic Go, you may end up with fewer conflicts. An exception is a cache, and there are specific implementations of that. Not every cache implementation fits every purpose.

Whatever the case, I am hoping we eventually will see a synchronized version of the Golang container library.  We use channels extensively -- but rarely as a signaling apparatus to synchronize access to restricted memory / objects.

What I meant was not to use channels as a mechanism for serialization. What I meant was to remodel the algorithm as goroutines using channels to communicate to eliminate the need for shared memory, hence the need for serialization. Granted, that does not always happen perfectly, but the need for shared collections decreases. Again: the needs of concurrency management over a container is very use-case specific, and generic solutions usually create unnecessary bottlenecks.

No, not in one place. Idiomatic Go programs typically don't need synchronized versions of collections types (more on that later). You would probably get a more useful answer if you asked how to write a certain concurrent algorithm idiomatically, or how to improve code using a non-standard concurrent collection. However, to answer this question, the following concurrent containers do exist, some of which are idiomatic.
Queues
Queues allow you to arbitrarily control concurrency:

Channels, a Go language feature. An idiomatic pattern involves a single goroutine that reads from a channel and accesses a non-synchronized datastructure.
enriquebris/goconcurrentqueue.{Fixed}FIFO
antigloss/go/concurrent/container/queue.LockfreeQueue

Maps
Maps allow you to persist key-value pairs:

sync.Map, optimized for read-heavy workloads or disjoint writes
orcaman/concurrent-map.ConcurrentMap, which claims to have better insertion performance

Caches
Caches allow you to reuse prior computations:

muesli/cache2go.CacheTable, items expire after user-defined lifespan
antigloss/go/v2@v2.0.0/cache/lru.Cache, LRU eviction policy

Pools
Pools allow you to optimize performance by reusing interchangeable values:

sync.Pool, for general purpose pools
antigloss/go/v2@v2.0.0/pool.{GoRoutine, Object, Buffer}Pool, for specialized pools

Ring buffers
Ring buffers make certain I/O operations more efficient:

smallnest/ringbuffer.RingBuffer, although it diverges significantly from container/ring by operating on bytes

Lists
Lists could replace container/list (although Queues, especially Channels, are much more idiomatic in concurrent Go):

zl14917/mastersproject/concurrent/vector.ConcurrentVector, contiguous memory
xphoenix/linkedlist.Node, doubly-linked list (⚠ no open-source license present at the time of writing)

Build your own
Building your own allows you to have, for example, a concurrent container/heap:

lock a sync.Mutex or sync.RWMutex before accessing any existing container
refactor your code so that only one goroutine accesses the container while, for example, processing a Queue

Note: Except for channels and sync.*, I haven't personally used these, and this is not an endorsement of their correctness or performance.
